# Is it possible to use Google's ortool in my script without downloaded ortool library?

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

Basically, I have to test my script on a server which I cant add new libraries. How do i write/change my

> from ortools.algorithms import pywrapknapsack_solver

in my .py file such that I can still utilise Google's ortool when i submit onto a server without ortools installed? Is there something like html tag  which i can just link to and use ortool library?
I have to sent my whole code.py file to test, and i **can** add along other .py files with my code.py.

I tried to download from Google the [source code](https://github.com/google/or-tools/tree/stable/ortools/linear_solver) but i dont know how to get it to work.

Currently my code.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from ortools.algorithms import pywrapknapsack_solver
def getBestSet(W, packages):
  final_arr = []

  pID = ['1','2','3','4','5'] #sample data
  values = [20,44,12,5,16]
  weights = [10,11,21,3,9]

  solver = pywrapknapsack_solver.KnapsackSolver(
        pywrapknapsack_solver.KnapsackSolver.
        KNAPSACK_MULTIDIMENSION_BRANCH_AND_BOUND_SOLVER, 'KnapsackExample')

  solver.Init(values, [weights], [W])
  computed_value = solver.Solve()

  packed_items = []
  packed_weights = []
  total_weight = 0
  # print('Total value =', computed_value)
  for i in range(len(values)):
      if solver.BestSolutionContains(i):
          packed_items.append(i)
          packed_weights.append(weights[i])
          total_weight += weights[i]
  # print('Total weight:', total_weight)
  # print('Packed items:', packed_items)
  # print('Packed_weights:', packed_weights)
  for i in packed_items:
    final_arr.append(pID[i])
  return final_arr
```

Comment: simple answer no. OR-Tools solvers are in C++. You need the python to load these modules to run or-tools.

Comment: I see.. thanks! it was for a class project so i dont think i can use the google colab.

Answer (score 1):

You can try on Google Colab.
To install or-tools, in the first cell, run !pip install ortools
then put your code in a new cell below the first one.